# How can we compute the time complexity of the below function

Tags: c++, algorithm

```
void f(int n) 
{
 doOh(n);
 if(n<1) return;
 for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
 {
   f(n/2);
 }
}
```

Time complexity of doOh(n) is O(N).
How can we compute the time complexity of the given function.

Comment: By writing a recurrence for the time compexity and solving via the Master Theorem.

Comment: Ask yourself, How often will the function call itself if n is very large? (2 times, half the size)

Comment: Can you please explain the computation, i am a beginner.

Comment: @tom: it is your duty to understand what the teacher explained, and practice. Otherwise you will not learn.

Answer (score 1):

Denoting the complexity as `T(n)`, the code says

```
T(n) = T0 if n = 0
     = O(n) + 2 T(n/2) otherwise
```

We can get an upper bound by replacing `O(n)` with `c n` for some `c`*, and we expand

```
T(n) = c n + 2 T(n/2)
     = c n + 2 c n/2 + 4 T(n/4) 
     = c n + 2 c n/2 + 4 c n/4 + 8 T(n/8) 
     = ...
```

The summation stops when `n < 2^l`, where `l` is the number of significant bits of `n`. Hence we conclude that

```
T(n) = O(l c n + 2^l T0) = O(l n).
```

---

*Technically, we can only do that as of `n >` some `N`. But this does not change the conclusion regarding the asymptotic behavior of `T`.

Comment: Your solution is correct, AFAIK, but I guess `O(n log n)` is easier to comprehend. It's just an opinion, may be wrong.

Comment: @user1984: `log n` would be unintuitive. `log2 n` is better. But IMO it is no sin to say that this the number of halvings until you get to zero, i.e. the number of bits. (Yes I know that newbies won't immediately relate this to the logarithm. Life is life.) I renamed `m` to `l`.

Comment: It's fine and correct. Don't worry :D

Answer (score 0):

**Complexity = O(nlog2n)**

The reason is

- Every time f(n) is called, doOh(n) is called. Its time complexity is O(n) when we pass n in f(n) as you mentioned
- f(n) will call f(n/2) 2 times. So time complexity will be 2*O(f(n/2)) = O(f(n/2))
- f(n) is becoming f(n/2). f(n/2) is becoming f(n/4) and so on... it means this f(n) will be called log2n times (logn base 2 times).
- Hence, doOh(n) will also create n + n/2 + n/4  and so on time complexity logn times.
- n or n/2 or n/4 all have O(n) complexity.
  Hence the total time complexity is O(logn) * O(n) which is order of nlogn base 2 = O(nlog2n)